# how can I assign variable b to indexes of the string a?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a problem with task.
Write a program that will replace the given position for the given string (also given by the user). The function has 3 parameters, string for analysis, position that should be replaced and the character that has services to be changed.
I tried it that way but it doesn't work. 
At the end there is the same string as at the beginning

```
a =input("enter string\n")
print(len(a))
for i in enumerate(a):
   print("individual indexes:",([i]))

b = input("enter the index number you want to replace\n")
b = str([a,i])
c = input("what do you want to change ?\n")
a1 = a.replace(b,c)
print(a1)
```

Comment: You should paste your code here, not as an image, but as text. Then you should say what doesn't work about it.

Comment: If any of the answers did help you, so please accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
b = int(b)
a1 = a[:b] + 'c' + a[b:]
```

```
a =input("enter string\n")
print(len(a))
for i in enumerate(a):
   print("individual indexes:",([i]))

b = int(input("enter the index number you want to replace\n"))
c = input("what do you want to change ?\n")
a1 = a[:b] + 'c' + a[b:]
print(a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a side note. Avoid using variable names such as: `a`, `b`...names should be meaningful.

For example:

1. `a`  -->  `input_str`
2. `b` --> `idx_to_change`
3. `c` --> `new_char`
4. `a1` --> `final_str`

A full working example:

```
input_str =input("enter string\n")
print(len(input_str))
for i in enumerate(input_str):
   print("individual indexes:",([i]))
idx_to_change = input("enter the index number you want to replace\n")
idx_to_change = input_str [int(idx_to_change)]
new_char = input("what do you want to change ?\n")
final_str = input_str.replace(idx_to_change, new_char)
print(final_str)
```